# Alternate figure and caption

Tags: floats, captions, sidecap

I'm using documentclass article.

I'm trying to achieve side captions to alternate.
Have nicely set them up for right-hand side, but alternating is a problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}       %% allow graphics
\newcommand{\xfig}[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\input{"figures/#2.pdftex_t"}}}

\usepackage[font=normalsize]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=beside,capbesideposition={top, outside}, floatwidth=0.7\textwidth, capbesidewidth=2\marginparwidth}
\captionsetup[capbesidefigure]{format=plain, justification=RaggedRight,
font=normalsize}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textbf{Case}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [t] 
   \scalebox{0.36}{\includegraphics*[viewport=190 35 1050 900]{figures/1.JPG}} 
 \caption{  \textbf{Date \linebreak \\  Procedure \linebreak \\  Doctorname \linebreak \\ Radiographer: \\  \quad \mbox{Allan} \linebreak \\ 2D \& 3D }}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure} [b] 
\caption{ \textbf{Date \linebreak \\  Procedure \linebreak \\  Doctorname \linebreak \\ Radiographer: \\  \quad \mbox{Allan} \linebreak \\ 2D \& 3D} }
   \scalebox{0.36}{\includegraphics*[viewport=190 35 1050 900]{figures/2.JPG}} 
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Question: Can I \floatsetup different figures - like figure1, figure2 etc. (substituting numbers unfortunately doesn't work)?

[image: This is what I want to achieve]
[image: Images and side caption so far]

Thank you for your feedback, so I hope the added information helps.

Comment: Why do you place the logo in a `figure` and why do you use `scalebox` in order to change the size of an image?  Wouldn't a simple `\hfill \includegraphics[scale=0.85]{Logo_full.jpg}` be sufficient to place the logo right alinged?

Comment: Also, all the manual linebreaks in side of the captions seem quite unusual. Could you please show a sketch of what you want to achieve? Please also make your code compilable (A `}` is missing inside of the titlepage). Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: Could it be possible that you want an imag ena some sort of table side by side instwad of an actial caption?